# BlackBerry - get only updated contacts from address book

Tags: blackberry, java-me, synchronization, addressbook, contacts

I have an application for get and send contacts from blackberry but i need to send only updted contacts instead of all, so can i get only updated contacts from blackberry ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**UPDATE**
<strike>You can use [REVISION](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/4.5.0api/javax/microedition/pim/Contact.html#REVISION) field to get last date and time that this contact's information was modified:</strike>

```
long lastChanges = contact.getDate(Contact.REVISION, 0);
```

So you can save Contacts last change date in Persistent Store and send them to server, next time check actual REVISION value and compare with saved value from Persistent Store.
Remember to handle **added** and **deleted** Contacts.

Wrong, tried this approach, REVISION field is not supported by BlackBerry contact list... See also [How to Get last contact modification When Revision field is not supported.](http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Java-Development/HELP-How-to-Get-last-contact-modification-When-Revision-field-is/td-p/255421;jsessionid=05F771607D0FC6225ADB8F8FFC1DEF66)

---

Other option is to use [BlackBerryContactList.addListener()](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/4.5.0api/net/rim/blackberry/api/pdap/BlackBerryContactList.html#addListener%28net.rim.blackberry.api.pdap.PIMListListener,%20boolean%29) and [PIMListListener](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/4.5.0api/net/rim/blackberry/api/pdap/PIMListListener.html), but its rather complex and will require background application running all the time.
**UPDATE** See example [Notify a BlackBerry device application when a contact list changes](http://docs.blackberry.com/en/developers/deliverables/11935/Notify_app_when_list_contacts_changes_565508_11.jsp)

---

Another thing you can do is store Contacts into Persistent Store and compare all fields before synch.
**UPDATE** You will have to copy Contact field values one by one into some [Persistable](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/4.0.2api/net/rim/device/api/util/Persistable.html) implementation (I would suggest vector). See [A13 – Storing Persistent Data](http://na.blackberry.com/developers/resources/A13_Storing_Persistent_Data_V2.pdf)

Comment: I like the idea of comparing fields before sync, but am unsure of performance impact for large number Contacts list. This part will need to be carefully designed.

Comment: I was trying for comapring fields but i am not able to store blackberrycontacts as a persistant store, its showing nonPersistableObject Exception. I am also running my application in background so how can i BlackBerryContactList.addListener() and PIMListListener for getting update contacts.